# Sort uitableview in ascending price list

Tags: iphone, uitableview

My app contain two array (ie productArray and priceArray) and pass the value of one array on cell. textlabel.text  and other array on cell.detaillabel.text.It is working fine .Now i want to sort uitableview in ascending price list. please guide me how to do it.. Here Is my code..

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
NSMutableArray *productArray;
NSMutableArray *priceArray;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *productArray;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *priceArray;
@end



 #import "RootViewController.h"



 @implementation RootViewController
 @synthesize productArray,priceArray;


 - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

    productArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"iphone",@"ipod",@"ipad",nil];
priceArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"4000",@"2000",@"100",@"1000",nil];

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
 }


 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark Table view data source

  // Customize the number of sections in the table view.
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 1;
}


 // Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section       {
  return [productsArray count];
}


  // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell.
cell.textLabel.text=[productsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[priceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
 }

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
// For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
  [super dealloc];
 }


 @end
```

Comment: You should put the original source code here, and not include the code from my suggestions, because the question will then be confusing to everyone else who sees it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading values from two different arrays to populate a tableview cell makes sorting difficult. I recommend you make a single object that contains both the product and price attributes, then store these objects in a single array. Then you can simply sort the array with a custom sorting method that compares the prices.

Example product class:

```
@interface Product : NSObject
{
    NSString *productName;
    NSString *price;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *productName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *price;
```

Then write a method that can sort products by price:

```
products = [products sortedArrayUsingSelector(sortByPrice:)];
```

...which calls this method in your products implementation:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)sortByPrice:(id)anObject
{
    if (self.price < anObject.price) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else (if self.price > anObject.price) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Store products in one array:

```
NSMutableArray *products;
```

And your cell values will be set by an object from a single, sorted array.

Creating a product changes from this:

```
[products addObject:@"Milk"];
[prices addObject:@"2.25"];
```

to this:

```
Product *newProduct = [[[Product alloc] init] autorelease];
[products addObject:newProduct];
[newProduct setProductName:@"Milk"];
[newProduct setPrice:@"2.25"];
```

And setting your cell values changes from this:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[productArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[priceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to this:

```
cell.textLabel.text=(Product *)[products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].productName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text=(Product *)[products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].price;
```

Comment: Should I use NSDictionary or something Else.. I am scratching my head..Please guide me or refer to me a tutorial.Thanks

Comment: one thing more .. how to pass value to cell.textlabel and cell.detaillabel.. I am doing this way but it is now showing anything.cell.textLabel.text=[products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.detailTextLabel.text=[products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: You can make productName and price synthesized properties. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I have updated my code according to your code..But it is giving an error....."Request for member 'productName' in something not a structure or union.. I know this error come when you dont synthesize. but why it is coming here?Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure without seeing all of your code. But instead of [products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].productName, use [[products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] productName] . You need to have a getter method for the productName variable, whether you @synthesize it or implement it yourself.

Comment: @bneely.. Thank you very much..It work. You are real savior for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @VivekSehrawat Could you please explain which parts you don't understand? You might be better served by asking a new question. If there is any unfamiliar code here, you might start with reviewing Apple's UITableView and UITableViewCell documentation, or by looking at some Objective-C programming tutorials.